# Changing login state don't change items on drawer with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, state, react-navigation-v5

Im really new to react and probably doing something stupid but cant found a working example then posting my question here.
I want change the content of drawer in function of the user have authenticated or not but it don't change when I click on "FAKE LOGIN".
Its a most MINIMAL code I cant think to reproduce it.
See the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
let hasLogin = false;

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}
        title="Go to login"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
          title="Go to Home"
        />
        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            hasLogin=true;
            navigation.navigate('Home')
          }}
          title="FAKE LOGIN"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  function ProfileScreen({ navigation }) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Button
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
            title="Go to Home"
          />
        </View>
      );
    }

const MenuItens = () => {
  let nmit = undefined;
  const [hasLogin, setHasLogin] = useState(false);
  if(hasLogin){
      nmit = <>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </>;
  } else {
      nmit = <>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      </>;
  }
  return (
      nmit
  )
}

export default function ShellNavigator() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        {MenuItens()}
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code does what you want, it maps states inside context:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text, Style } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
//----------------------------------------------------------------
import { createContext } from 'react';
const Context = createContext();
//----------------------------------------------------------------
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
//----------------------------------------------------------------
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const {state, setState} = useContext(Context)
  let trgScreen = ""
  if(state["hasLogin"] == "F"){
    trgScreen = "Login";
  } else {
    trgScreen = "Logout";
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(state)}</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={
          () => navigation.navigate({name:trgScreen})
        }
        title={'Go to ' + trgScreen}
        />
    </View>
  );
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------
function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
  const {state, setState} = useContext(Context)
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(state)}</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={
          () => navigation.navigate({name:'Home'})
        }
        title="Go to Home"
        />
      <Button 
        onPress={() => {
          setState({"hasLogin":"T", "user":"Mark"});
          navigation.navigate({name:'Home'})
        }}
        title="FAKE LOGIN"
        />
    </View>
  );
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------
function LogoutScreen({ navigation }) {
  const {state, setState} = useContext(Context)
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(state)}</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={
          () => navigation.navigate({name:'Home'})
        }
        title="Go to Home"
        />
      <Button
        onPress={
          () => {
            setState({"hasLogin":"F", "user":"Anon"});
            navigation.navigate({name:'Home'})
          }
        }
        title="FAKE LOGOUT"
        />
    </View>
  );
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------
function ProfileScreen({ navigation }) {
  const {state, setState} = useContext(Context)
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(state)}</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={
          () =>  navigation.navigate({name:'Home'})
        }
        title="Go to Home"
        />
    </View>
  );
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------
function MenuItens(hasLogin) {
  let nmit = undefined;
  if(hasLogin=="T"){
    nmit = <>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Logout" component={LogoutScreen} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
          </>;
  } else {
    nmit = <>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
          </>;
  }
  return (
    nmit
  )
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------
export default function ShellNavigator() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({"hasLogin":"F", "user":"Anon"})
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{state, setState}}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            {MenuItens(state["hasLogin"])}
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score -1):

What you want isn't possible, the drawer items cant be updated, its a fixed thing and cant see your state changing, just drop the react-navigation and drawer and do a navigation based on a bar with buttons, its easier and works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).